# How to inserting first node for singly linked list in Java?

Tags: java

i just try like that but no respons

```
 //addFirst
    public void addFirst(Object info) {
        MyNode newNode = new MyNode(info);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            MyNode cur = head;
            while (cur.getNext() == null) {
                cur = null;
            }
            newNode.setNext(head);
        }
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Comment: You should tell us what is the problem with the code.

Comment: Can you tell me which code is correct how to insert first for singly linked list? i really dont know @EyalSchneider

Comment: I presume you're inserting at the head, not the tail.  In that case, you've got lots of code here that you don't need.  All you need to do is to set `next` for the new node to `head`, and set `head` to the new node.  It works whether you're inserting the first node or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me, but that code doesn't seem right.  Have a look at ccjmne's answer (which is kind of equivalent to my previous comment).  It's not Java, but it does contain all the logic you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is the pseudo-code to implement the function you're looking for:

```
addFirst(obj):
    node = new node(obj)
    node.next = head
    head = node
;
```

It's up to you to translate it into Java code, if you don't mind ;)

Comment: @michaeladevi I'm glad to be of any help! Don't hesitate to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if you're done with that question ;)